# GET запрос к сайту на Java

Tags: java, url

Есть сайт, на главной странице которого есть форма поиска.

```
<div class="formText"><input id="search_input" class="text ui-autocomplete-input" name="kp_query" autocomplete="off" maxlength="256" value="" tabindex="1" type="text"><span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span></div>
<input class="searchButton1" value="" tabindex="2" onclick="if(!!document.getElementById('search_input').value &amp;&amp; document.getElementById('search_input').value != 'поиск') {document.searchForm.first.value = 'no'; document.searchForm.submit();}" type="button">
```

Результатом поиска является страница сайта, которая будет парсится средствами Java. 
Собственно вопрос, как сделать в Java  запрос поиска и получить адрес найденной страницы?  Если можно, хоть несколько строк кода.

Comment: Есть несколько http клиентов для java. Даже вроде встроенный есть, но точно не знаю, не использовал. А использовал apache http client. С помощью клиента выполняете запросы, получаете ответы. В зависимости от формата ответа применяется соответствующий парсер. Для xml или json парсер обычно всегда под рукой. А годный парсер html надо ещё поискать.

Comment: To @Sergey.  Вопрос не про парсеры, сам парсер уже написан и работает, вопрос, как запросом получить адрес страницы, которую надо парсить.

Comment: В первых строках своего предыдущего письма кажется упомянул про клиентов http. Гуглятся очень просто. Посмотрите, что есть сразу "в коробке" java - `HttpURLConnection`? Не понравится - рекомендую `apache http client`, Если и этот не понравится - ищите дальше, с другими не связывался. Не писать же за вас запрос.

Comment: Простой способ сделать запрос с "буржуйского" SO:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485708/how-do-i-do-a-http-get-in-java#1485730

Comment: Ответа так и не получил. Как использовать HTTP клиент я знаю, если известна результирующая страница сайта, то парсер работает.  Вопрос совсем о другом, мне нужно получить адрес этой страницы который возвращается при использовании формы поиска, код которой я привел.  Еще раз, мой вопрос это не как использовать Http клиент, а как для приведенного кода создать запрос, в котором передать требуемое значение и получить адрес найденной страницы.

Comment: Из Вашего вопроса не понятно, что Вам нужно. Можете отправить любой запрос, можете распарсить любую страницу, Так в чём собственно проблема-то? Не знаете как программно выполнить submit формы?

Comment: Да, именно, нужно програмно выполнить submit формы, а в приведенном коде формы непонятно.  Нужно программно передать строку в эту форму и получить ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по javascript'у в вашем примере, где то в исходной странице есть html элемент **form**, скорее всего с идентификатором "searchForm" (например так: name="searchForm"), в аттрибутах которого и должен быть указан адрес, куда отправляется запрос.

Comment: Ещё надо в запросе указать параметры этой формы. Строка поиска скорей всего это `<input id="search_input" class="text ui-autocomplete-input" name="kp_query"`. Значит должен быть параметр `kp_query`= `чего там ищите`. `document.searchForm.first.value = 'no'` намекает, что есть параметр `first` и его скорей всего надо установить в `no`. Таким образом  просмотреть форму, выявить параметры и отправить POST(скорей всего, POST или GET определяется одним из атрибутов form) запрос с этими параметрами, заполненными нужными значениями.

Comment: А можно попросить пример запроса? А то со скриптовыми языками у меня совсем плохо.

Comment: Проще, Если предоставите исходный html код страницы, из примера

Comment: @Tariel При чём тут скриптовый язык? Вы же на java хотели всё получить и результат поиска и т.д.? Вам нужно из кода страницы поиска узнать параметры, которые используются в форме и адрес, на который отправить запрос (с этими параметрами) и с него же  получите свою страницу для парсера. Сами не можете разобрать страницу поиска - приведите её полностью, а не два строчки.

Comment: @Sergey все правильно, я застрял именно на том, как узнать параметры и куда отправлять.  Из кода формы ничего не понятно.

Comment: @ygun Код довольно длинный, как его выложить?

Comment: @Tariel выложите на GitHub Gist или на Pastebin

Comment: Это какой-то сайт в интернете? Дайте просто ссылку на страницу.

Comment: https://www.kinopoisk.ru/

Comment: @Tariel https://www.kinopoisk.ru/index.php?kp_query=fast%20and%20furious

Comment: @ygun  К сожалению, не работает.  Возвращает код всей страницы. И разве в параметры запроса не надо указывать куда мы посылаем запрос (имя формы) и передавать команду "submit"?

Comment: @ygun  Спасибо.  Осталось только разобраться со случаями, когда возвращаются множественные значения (два и больше фильма с одним названием).

Comment: @Tariel собственно "https://www.kinopoisk.ru/index.php?kp_query=искомый_текст" это и есть тот GET запрос, который возвращает страницу с результатами поиска по ключевым словам "искомый_текст". Текст, который вы передаете в запросе должен быть закодирован при помощи URLEncoder. Т.е. в итоге строка запроса формируется так: String url = "https://www.kinopoisk.ru/index.php?kp_query=" + URLEncoder.encode("фильм", "UTF-8");

Comment: @Tariel множественные значения надо будет обработать в парсере.

Comment: @ygun   Спасибо.  Как я понял, кодирование нужно для правильной обработки пробелов и спецсимволов?  Одно слово на кириллице обрабатывается корректно.

Comment: @Tariel да, именно так